# When testing autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity with GARCH do you need to include the ind. variables?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, garch, arch

I have seen GARCH specified both ways... including the independent variables and excluding them.  In the latter, only the ARCH and GARCH term remain in the specified regression equation.  For testing for conditional heteroskedasticity which specification is best?

Comment: It depends on what kind of conditional heteroskedasticity you are interested in and want to test for. If you expect the conditional variance to depend on independent variables, then it would be logical to condition on them by including them in the conditional variance model; if not -- then not. If you give an example, we could discuss what would be more appropriate in that particular case.

Comment: Your comment makes perfect sense to me.  Is the heteroskedasticity associated with the level of the fitted value or estimated value?  Or do you want to go more granular and check whether the heteroskedasticity is associated with a particular independent variable(s).  In my mind, your comment qualifies as a good answer.  I would give it thumbs up.  You are welcome to structure it as such.

Comment: Richard, I am working on a company proprietary model so I can't share the specifics.  I'll use an example that replicates the situation. GNP ~ S&P500 + Housing price.  So, when I run a GARCH model (using EViews)... I first run it using only the ARCH and GARCH terms.  And, neither is statistically significant within the Variance Equation.  I run the GARCH model a second time, with the two independent variables.  Now, the GARCH term is very stat. significant and so is of the ind. variable.  What do you conclude in this situation?

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are doing. You run a simple regression of GNP on S&P500 and housing price. You obtain the residuals and build a GARCH model for them. The first time it is just GARCH(1,1); the second time it is GARCH(1,1) plus exogenous regressors S&P500 and housing price. Is that right? If the exogenous regressors in the GARCH model are significant, it shows that the variances varies as the exogenous variables vary. If the ARCH and GARCH terms are jointly significant, that shows there is a GARCH pattern, too, even after conditioning on the exogenous variables.

Comment: Continued: If the ARCH and GARCH terms are not jointly significant, maybe you should drop them and just condition the variance on the exogenous regressors. Also watch out for possibilities of getting a negative fitted variance; that could happen if the estimated coefficients on the exegenous regressors are negative in the GARCH model.

Comment: Richard, you understand my model framework precisely.  Just a couple of details.  All the original regressors have positive reg. coefficients within the original regression or Mean Equation of GARCH.  Out of four exogenous regressors (in my original model, not the example) only one is stat. significant.  The ARCH term is not sign. and has flipped signs within the GARCH(1,1) + exogenous variables.  In the GARCH(1,1) the ARCH term is positive but not stat. sign.  The GARCH term is not stat sign. in GARCH (1,1).  But, it is in GARCH(1,1) + ex. variables.

Comment: I am a bit lost in the details of the different models in the last comment. Anyhow, mind that statistical significance tends to increase with sample size, so do not rely on it too much. The individual significance of the ARCH term in a GARCH(1,1) model does not mean much -- because a GARCH(1,0) model (i.e. no ARCH term) does not make sense. I would have to think whether it might make sense when exogenous regressors are also present in the GARCH(1,1) model. A side note: in general, a problem with evaluating and validating GARCH models is that the conditional variance is unobserved...

Comment: Actually, this is a piece of the GARCH(1,1) model I really don't understand.  What is the dependent variable?  It is the variance of Y.  But, how do you calculate it for every single observations within the learning sample?

Comment: Since conditional variance is unobserved (and even unobservable) there really is no way to view it. One can only view fitted values that depend on the assumed specification of the conditional variance model. Andersen & Bollerslev [Answering the skeptics: Yes, standard volatility models do provide accurate forecasts](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.454&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (1998) is an article that discusses how to evaluate GARCH model fit, but I find it a bit difficult.

Comment: Richard, I'll read the article.  But, if you find it difficult, I most probably will find it obtuse.  So, how does GARCH structures the dependent variable?  I thought I read somewhere that it does simply take Residual^2 as a proxy for the residual's variance.  But, does that sound right to you?

Comment: Take a look at my comment [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143880/garch-volatility-forecast-model-in-practise). GARCH structures the dependent variable as $\sigma_t^2= \alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^q \alpha_i \epsilon_{t-i}^2 + \sum_{i=1}^p \beta_i \sigma_{t-i}^2$. Yes, $\epsilon_t^2$ is the most obvious proxy for $\sigma_t^2$. However, it may be a very noisy proxy so that it jumps around much more than the unobservable $\sigma_t^2$ does. That should be discussed in the Andersen & Bollerslev (1998) article.

Comment: Richard, I saw your answer and comment.  And, I am not sure if I understand them.  That's because if the variance is unobservable and is replaced by the proxy Residual^2... then on the righthand side of the equation, both the ARCH term = GARCH terms which does not sound right.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Perhaps my comment and answer were worder poorly and therefore were confusing. $\sigma_t^2$ is latent but that does not prohibit its use in the likelihood function for the GARCH model. $\varepsilon_t^2$ does not substitute for $\sigma_t^2$. Perhaps it's confusing to think that $\varepsilon_t^2$ ever substitutes for $\sigma_t^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of conditional heteroskedasticity you are interested in and want to test for. If you expect the conditional variance to depend on independent variables, then it would be logical to condition on them by including them in the conditional variance model; if not -- then not.

Comment: Richard, I give you +1 not only for a very good answer but also some excellent comments.  Anyone, before contributing on this issue is encouraged to read Richard's comments first.  I am not giving points for an answer that Richard has already fully addressed in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks! I am glad I could help. The simple answer and a few rather simple comments do not deserve this much praise, though. But thanks, I appreciate it!